# Confusion about objectify transactions retrying

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

The objectify [documentation](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Transactions) states this about transactions:

> Work MUST be idempotent. A variety of conditions, including
>   ConcurrentModificationException, can cause a transaction to retry. If
>   you need to limit the number of times a transaction can be tried, use
>   transactNew(int, Work).

However, the google datastore [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions) states:

> The Datastore API does **not** automatically retry transactions, but you
>   can add your own logic to retry them, for instance to handle conflicts
>   when another request updates the same entity at the same time.

These statements seem contradictory. Are objectify transactions really retried? Just to be safe I am using `transactNew(1, Work)` to make sure it runs only once, but what is going on under the hood and why?

The google documentation states that one use of transactions is to do things like transfer money from one account to another. If transactions are retrying then that would not work because by nature transferring money is not idempotent. In this case, using `transactNew(1, Work)` is the correct thing to do right? Basically, I am looking to do a non-idempotent transaction safely.

Comment: This may be dependent on the datastore client library used. For example the python `ndb` library automatically retries trasactions failed due to conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objectify will retry on CME. There is some question as to whether you can get a CME when the transaction actually commits - once upon a time it was documented that this was possible, but Google may have eliminated that.

Nevertheless, the "right way" to ensure a (say) bank transfer completes is not to limit the retries.

1. Create a transaction id outside of the retry. Just some unique value.
2. Start your transaction, attempt to load that transaction id. Does it exist? Your transaction is already complete.
3. If it didn't exist, create your transaction object (with the id) and do the debit + credit.

This ends up being pretty much standard behavior for any bank-like ledger; you create a transaction record along with the debit+credit. If you create a transaction record, it is easy to enforce idempotence.

Comment: How would you handle a transaction where you need to save an entity and increment a counter? If that were to retry, the entity would be saved twice (which is idempotent) but the counter would increase an extra time (which isn't idempotent.)

Comment: The same algorithm - you don't save the entity twice, you load and check for its existence first. You can reliably increment a count this way. However, counters are tough in the datastore due to mutation throughput limits. You can shard the counters but honestly if you're just maintaining a count of something like hits you're better off putting that in a different store.

Comment: I should note that all database technologies suffer from some variation of this count idempotency problem - if you make an increment to (say) postgres, and you get a timeout, did your count actually increment or not?

Comment: I have sharded counters, so a shard is incremented upon the saving of a certain entity. Sounds like my best option is to limit retries to only 1. If there is an error, the user can just try again. Do you foresee any issues with that by any chance?

Comment: No, that won't work. If you get a timeout (or other nonspecific) error, you have no way of knowing if the transaction succeeded or failed. Your counter may have incremented or it may not have. You can't know. This issue is not Cloud Datatastore specific and limiting the number of retries won't help you. "once and only once" semantic is fundamentally hard, but the technique to solve it is the same for pretty much every datastore technology.

Comment: But if a shard entity is incremented and saved (i.e. updated) inside a transaction, and the transaction fails for any reason, won't that shard save just be undone as if nothing happened?

Comment: Yes, the transaction will be atomic. But your application can experience error conditions like network timeouts and when that happens, you don't know if the transaction completed or not. This is a universal computing problem and if you are working with money (as in the original question) or other high-value data, you have to code around it.

Comment: So what you are saying is if there is something like a network timeout, the transaction won't know if it completed or not and thus won't roll back the datastore put operation inside it?

Comment: The transaction (ie, the database) will know. But your code won't. If you issue a database update that (only) increments a counter, and you get a timeout, your application has no way of knowing if the transaction succeeded or failed.

Comment: If the transaction times out and as long as any changes in the transaction are rolled back (such as multiple put operations and a counter increase), why is it an issue if the application knows or not? The end user can just retry the operation. My fear is that If I have a transaction where: a new entity is saved and a counter is incremented and saved, that the counter might get incremented twice. So long as that doesn't happen, the method can time out or fail or error. The end user can just receive the error and then retry the method again manually.

Comment: How does the user know if the counter was incremented or not? If the user sees that it incremented, how do they know it was because "their" transaction did it and not someone else's?

Comment: In my case, it doesn't matter if the user knows the counter was incremented or not. All that matters is that the transaction I described succeeded or did not. Maybe I do not understand your questions. Can you answer them for me? I am just trying to avoid my fear that I posted in the previous comment. That is all.

Comment: "Create a transaction id outside of the retry. Just some unique value." - By this do you mean use something like `factory().allocateId(MyEntity.class)` to make an ID and try to load the entity by that ID (i.e. key)?

Comment: Would your example work all the same if instead of an entity ID, I created a value for a specific field in the entity outside the transaction and then queried for an entity where the field equals that value? Would that ensure only one entity with a specific value for a field gets written?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at 2 different client libraries:

- the objectify one, which appears to be including automatic retries, customizable
- the plain datastore one which does not include such retries, you'd have to take care of the retries yourself

The money transfer problem isn't necessarily not idempotent, in the sense that it can be made idempotent using transactions. The key is to include both account modifications inside the same transaction, as shown in [the datastore client example](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#datastore-datastore-transactional-update-java):

```
void transferFunds(Key fromKey, Key toKey, long amount) {
  Transaction txn = datastore.newTransaction();
  try {
    List<Entity> entities = txn.fetch(fromKey, toKey);
    Entity from = entities.get(0);
    Entity updatedFrom =
        Entity.newBuilder(from).set("balance", from.getLong("balance") - amount).build();
    Entity to = entities.get(1);
    Entity updatedTo = Entity.newBuilder(to).set("balance", to.getLong("balance") + amount)
        .build();
    txn.put(updatedFrom, updatedTo);
    txn.commit();
  } finally {
    if (txn.isActive()) {
      txn.rollback();
    }
  }
}
```

This way either both accounts are updated, or none of them  is - if the transaction fails all changes are either not committed or rolled back.

FWIW, to verify my (`ndb`-based) transaction retry logic and idempotence I placed the transactions (with relevant debug messages) in push task queue handlers and triggered multiple tasks simultaneously to cause conflicts. The request and app logs were fairly sufficient for the verifications.

Comment: What about having a sharded counter where one shard (one entity)'s count is incremented and saved inside a transaction? Stickfigure's answer and comments suggest that a transaction could fail in a way that you don't know if the transaction succeed or not and thus (I think) no roll-back would occur.

Comment: If the code normally performing the rollback can't determine if it should rollback then I guess there would be no rollback. The approach, as Stickfigure suggested, would be to code for it. For example using a separate entity for the intent to perform a pending money transfer, then in the transfer transaction also add a reference to the intent entity so that you can then perform a final check if the intent was properly completed and finalize/cleanup the transfer or do a retry if needed. Expensive,  but it could be made reliable if needed - like for money transactions.

Comment: "If the code normally performing the rollback can't determine if it should rollback then I guess there would be no rollback" - that seems like something the google documentation should emphasize, because if this statement is possible then their money transfer example can backfire badly. I am just trying to get to the bottom of if that is true or not.

Comment: Micro, transactions in the datastore are atomic - they either complete entirely or they rollback entirely. So take away that worry. The problem is that if you approach transaction processing naively, you have no way of knowing which happened (commit or rollback) when certain types of (infrequent, but common) problems occur. If you don't care about that, fine. Whether or not Objectify retries on CME doesn't really matter - you probably want the retries.